# How can i receive images from whatsapp bot in twilio autopilot?

Tags: twilio, bots, whatsapp

How can I receive media in twilio autopilot from whatsapp? I have registered the autopilot webhook URL in the whatsapp sandbox. i have no space to register webhook for the media files.

Answer (score 1):

The Autopilot troubleshooting guide indicates Autopilot is currently unable to receive images.

Autopilot Troubleshooting
https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/troubleshooting